# How to remove file path encoding %20 in java

Tags: java, xml, windows, filepath, filenotfoundexception

I am tring to create a xml file in a specific path using java.
Problem is if I give file path with space it is encoding with '**%20**' in the blank spaces. 
    Kindly help me to solve this issue.

File path given by me - "F:/Backup Files/testng2.xml"
After encoding        - "F:/Backup%20Files/testng2.xml"

Code:

```
 TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
 Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
 DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
 StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("F:/Backup Files/testng2.xml"));       
 transformer.transform(source, result);
 System.out.println("File saved successfully");
```

Error:

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: F:\Backup%20Files\testng2.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.createResultContentHandler(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:297)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.transform(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:330)
    at FrameworkKeywords.ConfigurationFunctions.generateTestngXmlFile(ConfigurationFunctions.java:87)
    at FrameworkKeywords.ConfigurationFunctions.main(ConfigurationFunctions.java:29)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: F:\Backup%20Files\testng2.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.createResultContentHandler(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:287)
    ... 3 more
---------
java.io.FileNotFoundException: F:\Backup%20Files\testng2.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.createResultContentHandler(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:287)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.transform(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:330)
    at FrameworkKeywords.ConfigurationFunctions.generateTestngXmlFile(ConfigurationFunctions.java:87)
    at FrameworkKeywords.ConfigurationFunctions.main(ConfigurationFunctions.java:29)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding `.getAbsolutePath()` to your `File`,  as follows:

```
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("F:/Backup Files/testng2.xml").getAbsolutePath());        
    transformer.transform(source, result);
    System.out.println("File saved successfully");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Plirkee. your answer is very useful. It's working for me.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot, saved me very much time!